# EF: How to use custom selectors to project related entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Let's say I have 2 entities (1-to-many) relation: `Component` and `Part` like so:

```
public Component
{
   string CompName { get; set; }
   byte[] CompBlob { get; set; }
   ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}
public Part
{
   string PartName { get; set; }
   byte[] PartBlob { get; set; }
}
```

When I load a `Component`, I want to always load its `Parts` for this particular entity.

I want to know how to select / project a list of components so that EF will not load additional inner properties (eg: only `CompName` and `PartName` to be loaded but **not** `CompBlob` and inner `PartBlob`).

Maybe something like below, but how to apply a selector for `Parts`?

```
//
dbContext.Components.Include(c => c.Parts).Where(filterComponents).Select(.?.)
//
```

If needed, I have `LazyLoadingEnabled` set to false

Comment: What does the type you are projecting into look like? Is it simply a `CompName` string property with a collection of `PartName`'s?

Comment: To respond to your question, it is a new view-model class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using entity framework, you need to add primary key for each entity, like below:

```
public class Component
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompName { get; set; }
    public byte[] CompBlob { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}
public class Part
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public byte[] PartBlob { get; set; }
}
```

Then make the query like:

LazyLoading Disable Case:

```
var result = dbContext.Components.Include("Parts").Select(m => new 
             {m.CompName, PartNames = m.Parts.Select(n => n.PartName)}).ToList();
```

LazyLoading Enabled Case:

```
 var result = dbContext.Components.Select(m => new 
         {m.CompName, PartNames = m.Parts.Select(n => n.PartName)}).ToList();
```

Comment: Lin: Would it be possible to have a custom dynamic selector? ".Select(selector)" where selector is created programmatically? I am not quite sure how to achieve that.

Comment: hi @Cristi, take a look at the following link, it's about how to  select fields dynamically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly...

```
var query = dbContext.Components.Select(x => new {
        CompName = x.CompName,
        Parts = x.Parts.Select(p => p.PartName)
    }).ToList();
```

Add additional filters and selectors as you require.  You may / may not need the Include statement (.Include("Parts"))