# Linq dynamic select column and table

Tags: linq, dynamic

hello how I do dynamic select column query ?

example

```
 CrewEntities _DbEntities = new CrewEntities(); // I'm using object context



  public class CrewItem
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }
```

//I want to list only name column

```
var NameList = GetDynamicColumn("Name");
```

or

```
I want to list only LastName column 

var LastNameList = GetDynamicColumn("Name");



publict List<CrewItem> GetDynamicColumn(string Columm)
{
   var query = from p in _DbEntities.t_Crew
               select p.??? ;
}
```

and How do, I do dynamic select table query?

example

my sql table >> t_Crew , t_Person

```
var crewTable = GetDynamicTable("t_Crew");
var personTable = GetDynamicTable("t_Person");


    publict List<CrewItem> GetDynamicTable(string tableName)
    {
       var query = from p in _DbEntities.???
                   select p;
    }
```

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ : Dynamic select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select) (Just one of many). Please always first assume that your question has been asked before. Dynamic LINQ is a recurring topic at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question, If you are using Linq2SQL fro getting dynamic table data you can use this query

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetDynamicTable<TEntity>()
{
   return  _DbEntities.GetTable<TEntity>().Select(i => i);
}
```

or for having filter (where) you can write:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetDynamicTable<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
{
   return  _DbEntities.GetTable<TEntity>().Select(i => i).Where(expression).AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: hi Thank you for the answer how I do dynamic select column query ?
and I've installed Linq2SQL
http://www.nuget.org/packages/FlexLabs.Glimpse.Linq2Sql

but query did not work

Error 2 'CrewNetixData.CrewEntities' does not contain a definition for 'GetTable' and no extension method 'GetTable' accepting a first argument of type 'CrewNetixData.CrewEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\TFS\ShipProjects\ShipManager\Areas\CrewNetixData\Entity\Concrete\Crew.cs 505 32 CrewNetixData

Comment: @user3575477 DataContext has this method, if you are using Linq2SQL call getTable on DataContext, you can pass DataContext to youe method or have a general DataContext. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357220.aspx