# Web Api user filtering response fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a new web API and would like to allow the user to specify what fields get returned to them in the URL.

My current thoughts are:

For a sample model like this:

```
public class Value
{
    public string ValueId { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public ValueInternal Internal { get; set; }
}
public class ValueInternal
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

and a URL like this

```
http://example.com/api/values/?_fields=Number,Internal(Something)
```

would return this

```
[
   {
       "Number": 0,
       "Internal": {
           "Number": 0
       }
   }
]
```

I have come up with the below method of achieving this, but it has some flaws. I.e. it couldn't handle if `Internal` was an enumerable of `ValueInternal` or has no support for include all or include all except, or if T and TResult are different types. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can improve this or if there already exists a way of doing it that I am missing.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> CreateSelector<T, TResult>() where TResult : new()
    {
        var property = "Number,Internal(Something)";
        return arg => Process<T, TResult>(arg, default(TResult), property);
    }

    private static TResult Process<T, TResult>(T arg, TResult output, string propertyList) where TResult : new()
    {
        if (output == null)
        {
            output = new TResult();
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyList))
        {
            return output;
        }
        var properties = Regex.Split(propertyList, @"(?<!,[^(]+\([^)]+),");
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var propertyName = property;
            var propertyInternalsMatch = Regex.Match(property, @"\(.*(?<!,[^(]+\([^)]+)\)");
            var internalPropertyList = propertyInternalsMatch.Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(internalPropertyList))
            {
                propertyName = property.Replace(internalPropertyList, "");
                internalPropertyList = internalPropertyList.Replace("(", "");
                internalPropertyList = internalPropertyList.Replace(")", "");
            }
            var tProperty = arg.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            if(tProperty == null) continue;
            var tResultProperty = output.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            if(tResultProperty == null) continue;

            if (tProperty.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || tProperty.PropertyType.IsValueType || (tProperty.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
            {
                tResultProperty.SetValue(output, tProperty.GetValue(arg));
            }
            else
            {
                var propertyInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(tResultProperty.PropertyType);
                tResultProperty.SetValue(output, Process(tProperty.GetValue(arg), propertyInstance, internalPropertyList));
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
```

After a bit more reading I think I want to do something like the answer to this question [LINQ : Dynamic select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select) but that still has the same flaws my solution had

Answer (score 2):

If you use OData support on your ASP .NET Web API you can jus use [$select](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-$select,-$expand,-and-$value), but if you don't want to use it or your underlying system can't be easy queried using Linq, you can use a custom contract resolver, but in this case you are just reducing the serialization size, not the internal data traffic.

```
public class FieldsSelectContractResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        property.GetIsSpecified = (t) =>
        {
        var fields = HttpContext.Current.Request["fields"];

        if (fields != null)
        {
            return fields.IndexOf(member.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;
        }

        return true;
        };

        return property;
    }
}
```

and in WebApiConfig.cs set the custom contract resolver:

```
var jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new FieldsSelectContractResolver();
```

Comment: I did look at using OData and everything I saw about it was related to entity framework. I am not using entity framework. Is there a way to integrate OData with a generic LINQ provider?