# LINQ: Dynamic where with generic property and value

Tags: c#, linq, generics, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to build a simple select method for querying Linq-to-SQL table thru a generic static method. I'm stuck at creating the expression dynamically.

Same kind of question here: [LINQ : Dynamic select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select)

- **T** is the class of the database table (Person)
- **P** is the type of the value. The value and property types should be the same (F.ex String)
- **column** is the name of property on the given class ("Name")
- **value** is the where statement value for the field ("Jack")

F.ex Select all persons where name is "Jack" = **Person.Name = "Jack"**

```
public static List<T> selectBy<T,P>(String column, P value) where T : class {
    try {
        // First resolve the used table according to given type
        Table<T> table = database.GetTable<T>();

        // Get the property according to given column
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(column);

        //Func<Data,Data> expressionHere

        // Select all items that match the given expression
        List<T> objectList = table.Where(expressionHere).ToList<T>();

        // Return the filled list of found objects
        return objectList;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Debug.WriteLine("selectBy", ex.Message.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct the expression manually like this:

```
// First resolve the used table according to given type
Table<T> table = database.GetTable<T>();

// Get the property according to given column
PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(column);

//Func<Data,Data> expressionHere
ParameterExpression lambdaArg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
Expression propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(lambdaArg, property);
Expression propertyEquals = Expression.Equal(propertyAccess, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(P)));
Expression<Func<T, bool>> expressionHere = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(propertyEquals, lambdaArg);

// Select all items that match the given expression
List<T> objectList = table.Where(expressionHere).ToList<T>();

// Return the filled list of found objects
return objectList;
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer for now, thanks! I need to do some testing.

Comment: @Georg I have built a dynamic expression kind of like you describe. It works great for e.g LessThan or GreaterThan expressions. But if I Add two expressions together, it uses the '&' sign, I require it to be the string 'AND'. Can you tell me how to fix this, please?

Comment: @Jones not sure what you mean, I guess I need a bit more context. Please consider creating this as a new question.

Comment: @Georg Hi, I have discovered that I must use `.AndAlso`, then I get the correct behavior:
`// Combine expressions using AndAlso => 'AND' operand. Do not use And => '&'
queryExpression = Expression.AndAlso(smallerExp, largerExp);`
Thank you!