# Building a dynamic linq Func to return a string

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to figure out for a IQueryable how I can build a csv file by dynamically selecting objects as strings.

for example:

I read this about dynamically selecting properties of a T ...

[LINQ : Dynamic select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select)

That would allow me to do something like this ...

```
var data = new List<T> { items };
            var fields = new string[] { "Field1", "Field2", "Field3" };
            // build row strings
            var rows = set.Select(BuildRowObjectExpression<T, ProjectionOfT>(fields))
                .Select(i => Serialise<ProjectionOfT>(i));


        string Serialise<T>(T i, string separator)
        {
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            var values = new List<string>();
            foreach (var p in properties)
                values.Add(p.GetValue(i).ToString());

            return string.Join(separator, values);
        }

        Func<T, Tout> BuildRowObjectExpression<T, Tout>(string[] fields)
        {
            // input parameter "o"
            var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");

            // new statement "new Data()"
            var xNew = Expression.New(typeof(T));

            // create initializers
            var bindings = fields.Select(o => {

                    // property "Field1"
                    var mi = typeof(T).GetProperty(o);

                    // original value "o.Field1"
                    var xOriginal = Expression.Property(xParameter, mi);

                    // set value "Field1 = o.Field1"
                    return Expression.Bind(mi, xOriginal);
                }
            );

            // initialization "new T { Field1 = o.Field1, Field2 = o.Field2 }"
            var xInit = Expression.MemberInit(xNew, bindings);

            // expression "o => new T { Field1 = o.Field1, Field2 = o.Field2 }"
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(xInit, xParameter);

            // compile to Func<T, string>
            return lambda.Compile();
        }
```

What I was wondering however is:

**How do I build this as an expression / func that I can use with an IQueryable to do something like this**

```
// this would build me a string array from the specified properties 
// in a collection of T joining the values using the given separator 
var results = data.Select(i => BuildString(fields, "|")).ToArray();
```

I would ideally like to use this with an entity set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String conversion/concatenation is not a database job. You'd better keep the two parts separate - data retrieval in database query and data transformation in memory query.

For instance, you can use the following custom extensions methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Select<T>(this IQueryable source, string[] fields)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "o");
        var body = Expression.MemberInit(
            Expression.New(typeof(T)),
            fields.Select(field => Expression.Bind(
                typeof(T).GetProperty(field),
                Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, field))
            )
        );
        var selector = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
        var expression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Select", new[] { parameter.Type, body.Type },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector)
        );
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> Serialize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string separator)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        return source.Select(item => string.Join(separator, properties.Select(property => property.GetValue(item))));
    }
}
```

like this

```
var results = db.Data.Select<ProjectionOfT>(fields).Serialize("|");
```

If you want to avoid the `ProjectionOfT` class, there is no easy way to do that since it requires dynamic runtime class generation, so you'd better resort to `System.Linq.Dynamic` package.

Comment: Gah, it doesn't solve my actual problem but I don;t think it was a well worded question, that said it does solve the problem presented in the question.  Thx :)