# Extract Bindings from LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the next method:

```
public List<CustomType> GetRecords(Func<CustomType, AnotherType> members).
```

This method is called by different client applications.

It is possible extract the Bindings in members.Body?

It is possible change or remove the Bindings in members.Body?

How to?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "binding"? Give an example please.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, the client application creates a lambda expression using the next sentence: var xInit = Expression.MemberInit(type, bindings). I need to check the internal bindings for the expression

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy check the next URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select