# Reusable linq select query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my application multiple reports are needed on some table, many of the fields are common in most reports, as a sample:

```
public class ReportStudent
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Family {get; set;}
    public DateTime BirthDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime RegisterDate {get; set;}
    public Double Average {get; set;}
    public string FatherName {get; set;}
    public string MotherName {get; set;}
}

var list1 = context.Students.Select(e=> new ReportStudent
{
    Id = e.Id
    Name = e.Name
    Family = e.Family
    BirthDate = e.BirthDate
    RegisterDate = e.RegisterDate
    FatherName = e.FatherName
    MotherName = e.MotherName
}).ToList();

var list2 = context.Students.Select(e=> new ReportStudent
{
    Id = e.Id
    Name = e.Name
    Family = e.Family
    BirthDate = e.BirthDate
    RegisterDate = e.RegisterDate
    Average = e.Average
}).ToList();
```

How can I write this map only once? These fields are common in list1 and list2.

```
Id = e.Id
Name = e.Name
Family = e.Family
BirthDate = e.BirthDate
RegisterDate = e.RegisterDate
```

Comment: One word: AutoMapper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, define an expression that will contain your common projection needs:

```
Expression<Func<ReportStudent, ReportStudent>> commonProjection = e => new ReportStudent
{
    Id = e.Id,
    Name = e.Name,
    Family = e.Family,
    BirthDate = e.BirthDate,
    RegisterDate = e.RegisterDate,
};
```

Then have a method that will modify this expression to reflect the additional bindings:

```
public static Expression<Func<ReportStudent, ReportStudent>> MergeBindings(Expression<Func<ReportStudent, ReportStudent>> expr, Expression<Func<ReportStudent, ReportStudent>> newExpr)
{
    var reportStudentType = typeof(ReportStudent);
    var eParameter = expr.Parameters.First();
    var eNew = Expression.New(reportStudentType);

    var memberInitExpr = expr.Body as MemberInitExpression;
    var memberInitNewExpr = newExpr.Body as MemberInitExpression;
    var allBindings = memberInitExpr.Bindings.Concat(memberInitNewExpr.Bindings.Select(x =>
        Expression.Bind(x.Member, Expression.Property(eParameter, x.Member as PropertyInfo)
    )));

    var eInit = Expression.MemberInit(eNew, allBindings);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ReportStudent, ReportStudent>>(eInit, eParameter);

    return lambda;
}
```

Usage:

```
var withParentsExpr = MergeBindings(commonProjection, e => new ReportStudent
{
    FatherName = e.FatherName,
    MotherName = e.MotherName
});

var list1 = context.Students.Select(withParentsExpr).ToList();

var withAverageExpr = MergeBindings(commonProjection, e => new ReportStudent
{
    Average = e.Average
});

var list2 = context.Students.Select(withAverageExpr).ToList();
```

(With some help from @Nicholas Butler [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16517768/1625737))

Comment: tnx for answer, but an error exist "type arguments for method 'Queryable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly"

Comment: @MohammadAkbari, Where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: on select , context.Students.Select(withParentsExpr).ToList()

Comment: @MohammadAkbari, Did you change anything it the signature of `MergeBindings()`? What do you see when you hover on `var withParentsExpr`?

Comment: Expression<Func<ReportStudent, ReportStudent>>

Comment: That's strange. What type is `context.students` then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129898/discussion-between-mohammad-akbari-and-haim770).

Comment: context.Students id Student

Comment: You just needed () on the Expression. `context.Students.Select(withAverageExpr()).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write maps every time, you can use great library  http://automapper.org/
With this library, you can define map and it automatically map all properties

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function for that let say you have

```
public StudentReport ParseStudentReport(Student e)
{
    return new StutentReport{
         Id = e.Id
         Name = e.Name
         Family = e.Family
         BirthDate = e.BirthDate
         RegisterDate = e.RegisterDate
    }
 }
```

Then use it within your select statement

```
var list2 = context.Students.Select(ParseStudentReport);
```

Then add remaining properties or you could use AutoMapper, which can be found on github or as a nuget package.

Comment: how add remaining properties, plz give an example

Comment: This will not return an `Expression` that Entity Framework can translate into store query