# EF Dynamic Field Select using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have the following select:

```
var sortedCodes = Codes
.Where(c => c.Active)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.SortOrder)
.Select(b => new { b.Display, b.NumericCode, b.SortOrder })
.Distinct()
.ToList();
```

The table Code has many columns such as NumericCode, TextCode, AlphaCode, ThreeCode, FourCode, FiveCode. I am using this table to build selects in my UI. Is there a way I can create some dynamic code so I can pass in the column name to use for the value?

The above select would look like this:

```
.Select(b => new { b.Display, "TextCode", b.SortOrder })
```

I was thinking I could use an Expression, but I do not think this is exactly what I need as it is actually printing the lambda as the value.

```
var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Code), "b");
var body = Expression.Property(arg, valueColumn);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Code, string>>(body, arg);

var sortedCodes = Codes
.Where(c => c.Active)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.SortOrder)
.Select(b => new { b.Display, Value=lambda, b.SortOrder })
.Distinct()
.ToList();
```

Comment: One possible option is [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) package

Comment: I found the exact answer I wanted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45205267/2196799