# LINQ direct query for Select with Column Convert to String

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

For the below c#,  how I do make the "Id" column converted to a string? I needed to make this as a direct string query because the Second Column Name is variable, and I need a dynamic query to getData.

```
var stringValueLookupTable = await dbSet.Select(string.Format("new (Id, {0})", someStringVariable)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ : Dynamic select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select)

Comment: Are you using Dynamic LINQ? Why do you need to convert `Id` to a string?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to project the Id as string because I need to compare it to audit information which has Id stored as string.

My solution was to put *ToString() as Id*

var projectedResult =await dbSet.Select(string.Format("new (Id.ToString() as Id, {0})", someStringVariable)).ToListAsync();