# Retrieve user defined 'Combination of Columns' from database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, predicatebuilder

I need to retrieve user defined columns from database with Entity Framework.
I need to create column Projection based on passed collection, a List of strings, where each element contains column names,  with Entity Framework

I have a list of string which contains strings like this;

```
   List<string> columnsToSelect = new List<string>();
   columnsToSelect.Add("col1 + col2");
   columnsToSelect.Add("col2");
   columnsToSelect.Add("col3 + col4");
```

I have a table called 'RawData' with 6  columns like this:
Id EmpId col1   col2    col3    col4
[image: RawData Sample Table]

Now, if i were to query simple

```
var rawDatacolums = Context.RawData.where(a => a.EmpId = @EmpId)
```

this will generate SQL statement like this,

```
Select Id,EmpId,col1,col2,col3,col4 from  RawData
where EmpId = @EmpId
```

Here i want to pass columnsToSelect as argument and my result should be based on column selector i am passing in List

What i want to do is,

```
var rawDatacolums = Context.RawData.select(columnsToSelect).where(a => 
a.EmpId = @EmpId)
```

Which should generate SQL like;

```
Select col1 + col2 as Col1Col2, col2 as Col2, col3 + col4 as Col3Col4 
from  RawData where EmpId = @EmpId
```

I have tried to use "SelectProperties" from this article here:

https://byalexblog.net/entity-framework-dynamic-columns
https://github.com/lAnubisl/entity-framework-dynamic-queries/blob/master/entity-framework-dynamic-queries/SelectiveQuery.cs

```
var rawDatacolums = Context.RawData.SelectProperties(columnsToSelect)
```

if a pass exact columns like col1, col2 as list it works
but it doesn't work the way i want for example Sum of Two columns

My Requirement is i need to project addition of columns 
like 'col1 + col2' & 'col3 + col4'

**Updated Answer**

Based on couple of suggestions, i played more with Dynamic LINQ
and i made it work, i was able to apply various math conditions on my projection
and was able to create Dynamic Class out of it

The original github reference is as below:
https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic

but i found explanation here more useful please take a look here:
http://ak-dynamic-linq.azurewebsites.net/GettingStarted#conversions

Some other material i referred and had to use - which maybe helpful to someone is here - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Sample working code would look like this;

```
            var sampleQuery = "New(Col1+Col2 as Stage1Count)";
            IEnumerable queryResult= Context.RawData.AsQueryable().Select(sampleQuery );


            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug Sample Query: " + queryResult.ToString());
            foreach (var cust in queryResult)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug Sample StageCount : " + cust.ToString());
            }
```

Thanks all for your comments and suggestions! Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ : Dynamic select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select)

Comment: Do you really need to have the SQL compute the addition or would it be acceptable to return each column value and do the math on the client side?

Comment: Nope - i wish i have that option, in that case this problem wouldn't exist! :D 
The complicate part is the calculation on Projection. We have Requirement where instead of addition, you could possibly do subtraction, multiplication etc. 
So yes, 'SQL compute the addition' is the Key and Tricky part of this problem! :):)

Comment: I don't see why general expressions makes this less amenable to client side processing - unless you have huge expressions involving a lot of columns that mean each row will have to send a huge amount of data, just sending the needed columns and processing on the client should be about as efficient.

Comment: It won't because, this is a  datawarehouse schema, which can possibly have crazy number of columns, and we are dealing with millions of records per request - so we would like to avoid to bring such data in memory and apply math on it - it would be great if we can achieve via projection only

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic)

Comment: Hi Ivan - i have seen your response multiple places with respect to same kinds of question related to Dynamic EF Queries, i tried this Dynamic LINQ - but it didn't work for my requirement. Dynamic LINQ works if i pass the exact same column names in selector - here thats not the case - Thanks

Comment: Actually it's the only library I know which allows you to use expressions inside the `string` select list (because it contains string expression parser). All other questions/solutions you've mentioned receive just property names (or dot separated nested property paths) and simply build property accessors. Here you need string parser supporting +,- etc., so if that's library don't work for you, honestly I don't see which one would. Note that Dynamic LINQ  has it's own expression language - see [Dynamic Expressions](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions). Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obviously possible to create classes at runtime, or even new anonymous types, but they are extremely limited in how you can use them in your code.

If you prefer to work within the modern generic `Queryable` framework, and avoid creating classes at runtime that have limited compile time access, you can roll your own expression parser and build `Expression` trees. The trick is to use an Array type as the return from the `Select` to make the members accessible. This does mean all the expressions must return the same type, but this implementation will convert all the expressions to one type if necessary.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
public static class IQueryableExt {
    public static Expression<Func<TRec, TVal?[]>> SelectExpr<TRec, TVal>(this IEnumerable<string> strExprs) where TVal : struct {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TRec), "p");
        var exprs = strExprs.Select(se => {
            var e = se.ParseExpression(p);
            return e.Type.IsNullableType() && e.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(TVal) ? e : Expression.Convert(e, typeof(TVal?));
        }).ToArray();

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TRec, TVal?[]>>(Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(TVal?), exprs), p);
    }

    static char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
    static Regex tokenRE = new Regex($@"(?=[-+*/()])|(?<=[-+*/()])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    static HashSet<char> hsOperators = operators.ToHashSet();
    static Dictionary<char, ExpressionType> opType = new Dictionary<char, ExpressionType>() {
        { '*', ExpressionType.Multiply },
        { '/', ExpressionType.Divide },
        { '+', ExpressionType.Add },
        { '-', ExpressionType.Subtract }
    };

    static int opPriority(char op) => hsOperators.Contains(op) ? Array.IndexOf(operators, op) >> 1 : (op == ')' ? -1 : -2);

    public static Expression ParseExpression(this string expr, ParameterExpression dbParam) {
        var opStack = new Stack<char>();
        opStack.Push('(');
        var operandStack = new Stack<Expression>();

        foreach (var t in tokenRE.Split(expr).Where(t => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(t)).Append(")")) {
            if (t.Length > 1) // process column name
                operandStack.Push(Expression.PropertyOrField(dbParam, t));
            else {
                while (t[0] != '(' && opPriority(opStack.Peek()) >= opPriority(t[0])) {
                    var curOp = opStack.Pop();
                    var right = operandStack.Pop();
                    var left = operandStack.Pop();
                    if (right.Type != left.Type) {
                        if (right.Type.IsNullableType())
                            left = Expression.Convert(left, right.Type);
                        else if (left.Type.IsNullableType())
                            right = Expression.Convert(right, left.Type);
                        else
                            throw new Exception($"Incompatible types for operator{curOp}: {left.Type.Name}, {right.Type.Name}");
                    }
                    operandStack.Push(Expression.MakeBinary(opType[curOp], left, right));
                }
                if (t[0] != ')')
                    opStack.Push(t[0]);
                else
                    opStack.Pop(); // pop (
            }
        }
        return operandStack.Pop();
    }

    public static bool IsNullableType(this Type nullableType) =>
    // instantiated generic type only                
        nullableType.IsGenericType &&
        !nullableType.IsGenericTypeDefinition &&
        Object.ReferenceEquals(nullableType.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), typeof(Nullable<>));
}
```

Unfortunately type inference can't easily get the answer type, so you have to manually pass in the record type and answer type. Note there's special code in the parser to handle conversion to (common in SQL) nullable types when mixing nullable and non-nullable.

Given the `columnsToSelect` you provided as an example:

```
List<string> columnsToSelect = new List<string>();
columnsToSelect.Add("col1 + col2");
columnsToSelect.Add("col2");
columnsToSelect.Add("col3 + col4");
```

You can query the database like so:

```
var queryResult= Context.RawData.Select(columnsToSelect.SelectExpr<TRawData, int>());
```

And `queryResult` would be of type `IQueryable<int[]>` or `IQueryable<int?[]>` depending on the SQL column types.

Comment: Great Post - I will surely play-around with it.

For now, i am creating Run time string with whatever operations i need on columns, for example `string addQueryStringCol12 = "col1 + col2"`  and just passing it as selector using 
[Dynamic Linq](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic)  - as everyone has suggested. But my final query is coming up bit complex and i am now working on it to simplify as it impacts performance. 

I will play with the same of your code ( with your permission )  and will update you how it goes! Many thanks for your time and effort - really appreciate!

Comment: @vran It is for you to use anyway you need.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Great thing about this sample is, i have IQueryable<int[]> for my columns which makes my life much easy! :) :)