# System.Text.Json --> Only serialize specific fields per call

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

In a .NET Core 3 web API, I want to serialize an object with many properties. Depending on the caller's permissions, I want to show or hide specific properties. For now, I'm working with the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute exclusively. This is fine for properties, that you generally don't want to serialize.

But is there something similar like a `[JsonIgnore(context => context.CheckUserPermissions())]`? Or maybe something that I can add to my API method?

My current code is pretty simple:

```cs
[HttpGet("PickingZoneLists/{pickingZone}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<PickingListEntry[]>> GetData(string pickingZone) {
    // Get data
    dsyWorkOrder[] workOrders;

    try {
        workOrders = await GetPickingDocList(pickingZone);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Problem("Data could not be gathered. " + ex.Message);
    }

    // Validate result
    if (workOrders == null)
        return Problem("Service returned invalid data.");

    if (workOrders.Length == 0)
        return NotFound();

    // Transform data
    PickingListEntry[] result;

    try {
        result = PickingListEntry.FromServiceResponse(workOrders).ToArray();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Problem("Data could not be transformed. " + ex.Message);
    }

    // Maybe apply the filters to PickingListEntry here <-------------------

    // Create response object and return
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: Please, share your code and reproducible sample

Comment: What you're looking for is "conditional serialization"; most serializers support this out of the box, usually by if you have a property called `Foo`, you just add a method `bool ShouldSerializeFoo() { ... }` (sometimes the method needs to be `public` - for example `XmlSerializer`) and return `true` or `false` depending on whether you want to include it. Does this work in this case?

Comment: I don't think `System.Text.Json` supports `ShouldSerialize...`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski There is not much to show. It's just a simple API method which selects an object from a database and returns it to the client. I will add the code.

Comment: @MarcGravell I believe, that I've seen something like that in JSON.net. Is there something similar for Microsoft's new `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: `System.Text.Json` doesn't support (yet) some advanced scenarios available in `Json.NET`

Comment: @AndréReichelt yes, I'm sure Json.NET supports it; no idea about System.Text.Json, but it wouldn't amaze me if it is a gap

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I'm biased, but if I was writing/maintaining a serializer (cough, which I have), I'd list that under the "core/minimal features" bucket, or at least a "tranche B" feature

Comment: @MarcGravell There is a [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#conditionally-ignore-a-property) and particular part about ignoring a property. it doesn't allow you to _Ignore selected properties based on arbitrary criteria evaluated at run time_ I guess that OP wants exactly this option. Of course, you can try to cover it by creating a [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Under those circumstances, would you suggest me to better switch to the good old JSON.net, or should I dig down that rabbit hole and write my own custom converter?

Comment: @AndréReichelt I would say "it depends" :) Only you can compare the effort of both options for your codebase and estimate a time for that. I'd like to suggest you have a look a guides, which were posted above and do a basic scenario to check and compare what is better for you

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use a serialization process as a security gate keeper for your application data? Seems to me that's going to lead to issues in maintainability. are you able to scale the possible data views down to a handful and just return one based on application role?

Comment: why don't you return custom models per response type?

Comment: @Mike-314 One of the core features of the application is, that you can enable and disable each property on a per-user basis.

Comment: @DanielA.White There are 30 possible properties and each of them could be enabled or disabled on a per-user basis. So basically no.

Comment: @AndréReichelt I guess my concerns would be: 1, I think that by using attributes you are essentially making 30 decisions (with x amount of work) for each N number of records where you should just be able to make 30 decisions once. I think you'd be better off to just get from your data source the data you need. 2, maintainability, I don't think this would be apparent to future devs, but you could fix that by thoroughly notating the code.

Comment: @Mike-314 Well, I have a list of all relevant property names per request. Therefore something like `JsonResult.FromObject(myObj).FilterAttributes(stringListOfAttributeNames)` would be a (theoretical) option.

Comment: @AndréReichelt if you have the list of attributes, maybe you can use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select to filter before you transform to json

Comment: You can get System.Text.Json to ignore properties with NULL values, I know it's not a 100% soltuion but it might be worth considering. Properties that you dont want to be serialised just leave them as NULL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#exclude-all-null-value-properties    Only problem is if a property doesnt have any data but you do want it to be included.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach is to have dedicated dto types for each security level/role.

This way ensures that you never reveal information that is not meant to be revealed.

If you wish to stay with a single type you could create a method that makes all undesirable properties null and then serialise this object with `JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull`. This is still safe because in the event the seraliser is not configured correctly you're only exposing the names of fields, not their values.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
};
```