# How to convert string variable into property in EF Core in the select statement

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Good day everyone,

a property or a field name of a table is being stored in another table field [I know bad database design practice], so what I'm trying to do is converting the string into a variable using `GetType().GetProperty("some string goes here")` technique in the select statement like this `Select(m => m.GetType().GetProperty(x.data))`, though, everytime I try to execute the statement an error is thrown:

`` Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo]' does not match the corresponding member type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo]' (Parameter 'arguments[3]') ``

Comment: Do all fields have the same type?

Comment: Yeah, all fields are string

Comment: `know bad database design practice` don't do this then. ORMs are meant to map objects to relational tables anyway, and that design is *not* a table. On the Object side, you're supposed to have actual objects, not tables. Trying to fix the schema at the *query* is exactly the wrong place to do this. The problem is in the *mapping* logic, not the query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it's not up to me, I'm a mere developer, not the project leader, so I can't express my opinion, all I can do is execute the orders.

Comment: That doesn't mean what you want is possible, or that it's any better than rewriting everything. Unless you misunderstood the request. Inheritance in ORMs is often handled by using different tables per type, either holding all fields (Table-per-Class), or holding just the extra fields (Table-per-Type). Using a field value in one field to look up a field in another table simply isn't supported by ORMs.

Comment: In any case, you need to post the actual classes and tables. Trying to perform the mapping at the query level is simply wrong. The query needs to be translated to SQL and the code you tried can't be translated at all

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do think in EF Core query. Maybe you can do this after the query execution like `context.MyTable.ToList().Select(...)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ : Dynamic select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select)