# Linq To Sql - Dynamic column Select() from string array (Linq2Sql)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm looking to create a method that does something like **ConvertFieldNamesToSelect** below, which would dynamically create the select expression from a string array of column names, but I'm not sure if it's possible?

```
using (var dc = new MyDataContext(myConnectionStr))
{
    IQueryable<User> query = dc.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == 4);
    List<User> users = query.Select(ConvertFieldNamesToSelect<User>(new string[] { "UserID", "Name" })).ToList();
    return users;
}
```

I've seen threads like: [LINQ : Dynamic select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select/16517768)

Unfortunately they don't work correctly with Linq To Sql. At database level they either select all fields then refine afterwards (inefficent, visible via profiler) or throw an exception *Explicit construction of entity type 'X' in query is not allowed* because they are attempting to create an e.g. User() object in the query (rather than a dynamic object), which Linq To Sql doesn't allow, but regular Linq on lists does.

*dc.ExecuteQuery(sql)* could of course select the fields via a SQL statement, but that would mean *IQueryable* benefits are lost, and we have lots of existing code building those up dynamically. Would also consider DynamicLinq if that's an option.

Comment: I would suggest you look into [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core), just be careful of user inputs. Otherwise you would need to create your own code to create objects (e.g. consider: LINQ to SQL expects an object from the database like `User` to have all fields matching the database. You can't create a partial `User` object and expect it to work properly.)

Comment: @NetMage As touched upon I'm not entirely sure it is possible in Dynamic LINQ or by creating a custom Expression Tree (which I'd imagine DLinq is wrapping), since the problem is expressions can't create dynamic/anonymous types, which are worked out at compile time and Linq To SQL requires. It may be that I need to give up with strings arrays for field names and pass through TEntity expressions with dynamic object funcs higher up the chain.

Comment: Dynamic LINQ includes the code to create anonymous classes/types at runtime (I have my own cobbled together module to do it as well, though I cheat a bit). The issue is your result is going to be `List<object>` because you don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: Thanks @NetMage, that sounds encouraging, will dig in. List<object> should be fine and castable back to TEntity.

Comment: @NetMage ah, I'm assuming you just reflect the properties out of the temporary anonymous type via DynamicClass in Dynamic LINQ? Seems to work e.g. query.Select("new (UserID, Name)")

Comment: Normally in a dynamic situation you would use the result in a context such as a `GridView` which will handle the reflection for you. It really depends on your final use of such a dynamic object - e.g. I would often consider using a `DataTable` or `Dictionary` instead of Reflection if I needed to process the fields a lot.